# LibGit2SharpException v0.26.0.0 - git fetch exposes an exception 'too many redirects or authentication replays private repository'

Tags: c#, .net, github, repository

I am using LibGit2Sharp library to fetch code from my private repository, but I am experiencing an exception below

> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: too many redirects or authentication replays private repository

Here is my git fetch function

```
public static void GitFetch()
    {
        string USERNAME = "myusername";
        string PASSWORD = "mypassword";

        string logMessage = "";
        using (var repo = new Repository(@"D:\GitHub\my-test-repo"))
        {
            FetchOptions options = new FetchOptions();
            options.CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler((url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
                {
                    Username = USERNAME,
                    Password = PASSWORD
                });

            foreach (Remote remote in repo.Network.Remotes)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> refSpecs = remote.FetchRefSpecs.Select(x => x.Specification);
                Commands.Fetch(repo, remote.Name, refSpecs, options, logMessage);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
    }
```

The exception is exposed at the line

> Commands.Fetch(repo, remote.Name, refSpecs, options, logMessage);

Could anyone tell me what I am wrong please? And any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, although I'm using an AccessKey instead of a password. Although my token hadn't expired, regenerating it fixed the issue. Not sure if changing your password might result in a similar fix.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I will give that a try